# How does `plot` know how to plot an object without further specification?

Tags: r, class, plot

With R base function `plot` we can make different plots just by providing the data, without specifying further arguments. For example, if we plot a time series, using `plot(my_ts)` calls `plot.ts(my_ts)` because `my_ts` is class `ts`.

Similarly, we can use plot ANOVA results without any arguments. Here some ANOVA model:

```
data <- data.frame(group = c(rep("group_1",25),rep("group_2",25)), scores = c(runif(25,0,1),runif(25,1.5,2.5)))
mod1 <- aov(scores~group,data=data)
```

Using `plot(mod1)` works but `plot(summary(mod1))` results in the error

> "Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) :
> 'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'".

It seems like the `plot` function looks for data named `x` and `y` while trying to automatically create a plot without any arguments. I tried `names(mod1)` but couldn't find any `x` or `y`. So how does it come that `plot(mod1)` works but `plot(summary(mod1))` does not?

Comment: Because `summary(mod1)` returns an object of class c(`summary.aov`, `listof`) and there is no built-in `plot.summary.aov` function.  Out of interest, what do you *expect* a plot of a summary of an ANOVA to display?

Comment: What you’re seeing is [S3 method dispatch](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/s3.html) (or lack thereof, for the summary object).

Comment: @Limey Actually my question is not about plotting an aov summery object but, as I know now, about S3 method dispatch. I build a package that shall react differently depending on the provided class. That is the background of my question.

Comment: Ah!  Fair enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple methods which are called depending on `class(x)` when typing `plot(x)`. This is called method dispatch. One can also create new own methods e.g. `plot.summary.aov` for summary objects:

```r
data <- data.frame(group = c(rep("group_1",25),rep("group_2",25)), scores = c(runif(25,0,1),runif(25,1.5,2.5)))
mod1 <- aov(scores~group,data=data)

plot(mod1)
```

[image][image]

Let's define a new stub plot function

```r
plot.summary.aov <- function(x) {
  plot(iris)
}

plot(summary(mod1))
```

[image]

```r
methods(plot)
#>  [1] plot.acf*           plot.data.frame*    plot.decomposed.ts*
#>  [4] plot.default        plot.dendrogram*    plot.density*      
#>  [7] plot.ecdf           plot.factor*        plot.formula*      
#> [10] plot.function       plot.hclust*        plot.histogram*    
#> [13] plot.HoltWinters*   plot.isoreg*        plot.lm*           
#> [16] plot.medpolish*     plot.mlm*           plot.ppr*          
#> [19] plot.prcomp*        plot.princomp*      plot.profile.nls*  
#> [22] plot.R6*            plot.raster*        plot.spec*         
#> [25] plot.stepfun        plot.stl*           plot.summary.aov   
#> [28] plot.table*         plot.ts             plot.tskernel*     
#> [31] plot.TukeyHSD*     
#> see '?methods' for accessing help and source code
```